# How to see the array results of the generated table in php

Tags: php, arrays

So this is the some part of the code I study:

```
if ($handle) {
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
$exploded_line = explode("::", $line);
$day = date("j", $exploded_line[0]);
$action = trim($exploded_line[4]);

if ($action == LOGIN_ACTION) {
    $details[$exploded_line[3]][$day] = isset($details[$exploded_line[3]][$day]) ? $details[$exploded_line[3]][$day] + 1 : 1;   
} else if ($action == COMPANY_TICKETS_ACTION || $action == MYTICKETS_ACTION) {
    $company_mytickets_action[$day] = isset($company_mytickets_action[$day]) ? $company_mytickets_action[$day] + 1 : 1; 
} else if ($action == NEW_TICKET_ACTION) {
    $new_ticket_action[$day] = isset($new_ticket_action[$day]) ? $new_ticket_action[$day] + 1 : 1;
} else if ($action == SEARCH_ACTION) {
    $search_action[$day] = isset($search_action[$day]) ? $search_action[$day] + 1 : 1;
} else if ($action == PREFERENCES_ACTION) {
    $preferences_action[$day] = isset($preferences_action[$day]) ? $preferences_action[$day] + 1 : 1;
}
}

} else {
$data['html'] = ERR_MSG;
}

fclose($handle);
print_r();

foreach ($details as $users => $value) {
$data['html'] .= "<tr><td>$users</td>";
for ($x = 1; $x <= $calendar_days; $x++){
    //$details[$users][$x] = empty($details[$users][$x]) ? SPACE : $details[$users][$x];
    if(empty($details[$users][$x]))
        $details[$users][$x]='';
    else
        $details[$users][$x];

    $data['html'] .= "<td>" . $details[$users][$x] . "</td>";

    $unique[$x] = $details[$users][$x] == SPACE ? $unique[$x] : $unique[$x] + 1;
    $total[$x] = $details[$users][$x] == SPACE ? $total[$x] : $total[$x] + $details[$users][$x]; 
}
$data['html'] . "</tr>";
```

}

Now I want to var_dump the results to array. I try this `print_r($details[$exploded_line[3]][$day])`; but there is no display in the browser. How can I get the results in array? Thanks

Comment: var dump the variable details check if has any data

Comment: Thank you @OliSoproniB. . I saw the results now.